# Android build crash on startup

Tags: android

I implemented the google play game services to my game for leaderboards and achievements, my game builds normally, but when I try to launch it on android, it crashes before the unity splash logo shows, logcat gives me this:

```
com.FarSouth.RocketJumper/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
 03-03 16:48:59.617  2993  2993 D ActivityManager: starting Active launch
 03-03 16:48:59.648  2993  5385 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN typ=null flg=0x10200000 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.FarSouth.RocketJumper/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}} from uid 10077
 03-03 16:48:59.665  2993  3769 I ActivityManager: DSS on for com.FarSouth.RocketJumper and scale is 0.75
 03-03 16:48:59.702  2993  3628 D ActivityManager: isScaleDownAnimationEnabled() : false
 03-03 16:48:59.702  2993  3628 D ActivityManager: applyOptionsLocked, ANIM_CUSTOM_SCALE_UP, x : 803, y : 879, isHomeItem : false
 03-03 16:48:59.702  2993  3628 D ActivityManager: applyOptionsLocked, ANIM_CUSTOM_SCALE_UP, task.getRootActivity() : ActivityRecord{f3e35f2 u0 com.FarSouth.RocketJumper/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t21599}, task.getTaskToReturnTo() : 1
 03-03 16:48:59.702  2993  3628 D ActivityManager: setAppIconInfo(), x : 803, y : 879, width : 251, height : 312, isHomeItem : false
 03-03 16:48:59.704  2993  3628 I ActivityManager: Config changes=480 {0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 206mcc10mnc [pt_BR,fr_BE] ldltr sw360dp w640dp h336dp 480dpi nrml long land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1920, 1080) s.21}
 03-03 16:48:59.724  2993  3628 I ActivityManager: Override config changes=480 {0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 206mcc10mnc [pt_BR,fr_BE] ldltr sw360dp w640dp h336dp 480dpi nrml long land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1920, 1080) s.21} for displayId=0
 03-03 16:48:59.762  2993  3314 D ActivityManager: package  com.samsung.android.game.gametools, user - 0 is SDcard whitelisted
 03-03 16:48:59.775  2993  3314 I ActivityManager: Start proc 32163:com.samsung.android.game.gametools/u0a27 for service com.samsung.android.game.gametools/.floatingui.service.external.GameToolsIntentService
 03-03 16:48:59.781  2993  5473 W ActivityManager: crash : com.FarSouth.RocketJumper,0
 03-03 16:48:59.795  2993  5473 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.FarSouth.RocketJumper/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
 03-03 16:48:59.817  2993  5385 I ActivityManager: DSS on for com.samsung.android.game.gametools and scale is 1.0
 03-03 16:48:59.857  2993  3628 I ActivityManager: Config changes=480 {0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 206mcc10mnc [pt_BR,fr_BE] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h616dp 480dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) s.22}
 03-03 16:48:59.884  2993  3628 I ActivityManager: Override config changes=480 {0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 206mcc10mnc [pt_BR,fr_BE] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h616dp 480dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) s.22} for displayId=0
 03-03 16:48:59.914  2993  3027 I ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package com.FarSouth.RocketJumper u0
 03-03 16:48:59.995  2993  5329 D PackageManager: getSelectedMetaData : packageName(com.FarSouth.RocketJumper) or Metadata strings {[Ljava.lang.String;@b99c7e3}
 03-03 16:49:00.307  2993  3026 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{f3e35f2 u0 com.FarSouth.RocketJumper/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t21599 f}
 03-03 16:49:00.313  2993  3026 D ActivityManager: isScaleDownAnimationEnabled() : true
 03-03 16:49:00.313  2993  3026 D ActivityManager: clearAppIconInfo()
 03-03 16:49:00.313  2993  3026 D ActivityManager: applyOptionsLocked, ANIM_CUSTOM_SCALE_DOWN
 03-03 16:49:00.343  2993  5329 D ActivityManager: post active user change for 0 fullscreen true isHomeActivity() true
```

I don't have any experience with crash logs but it seems that its either Android Game Tools or Unity Player Activity that's crashing my game? Thanks in advance.

meta-data :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="unity.build-id"
        android:value="6b284c64-7566-47cb-9669-d2c3a8462673" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="unity.splash-mode"
        android:value="0" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="unity.splash-enable"
        android:value="true" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.VERSION"
        android:value="27.0.0-SNAPSHOT" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.1.0" />

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x0103000f"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:configChanges="0xfb0" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:authorities="com.FarSouth.RocketJumper.mobileadsinitprovider"
        android:initOrder="100" />

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x01030010"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" />

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService"
        android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION"
        android:exported="true" />

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x01030010"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
        android:exported="false" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@ref/0x7f070001" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="865302540267" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.unityVersion"
        android:value="0.9.61" />

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x01030011"
        android:name="com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity" />
</application>
```